# How to get photo metadata (for example camera model) using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo-metadata this documentation is useless because I've tried a lot and can't get camera_model from photo using latest version of graph api.

Comment: No any specific language just using Graph API explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: First I've GET my photos /me/photos then trying to get photo metadata and no result /{photo_id}?fields=camera_model